# Moongoose: Find name in another selection

Tags: javascript, node.js, find, express, mongoose

Im trying to get the name of a user by looking in up with a id.

```
query.find(function(err, dat) {
  for(i in dat) {
    users.findOne({_id: dat[i].owner}, function(userErr, user) {
      dat[i].ownerName = user.name;
      if(parseInt(i)+1==dat.length) res.render('view', {local: dat});
    });
  }
});
```

Hope you guys understand. Im trying to get a name from another selection in a query. But the problem is, that I cant save a variable outside the user query callback. How do i do this the right way? :-)

At the example a post above i only get the last one in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document you want to get from the innder ( second ? ) find is related in some way with the first query's documents, I suggest you define a DBRef-like relation in your schema or models and use `populate()` like shown in the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

**Quick example:**

Let's say you want to find all `Posts` talking about caffeine, whose author is the currently logged in `user`. First, define your models:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String
  , email   : Number
  , posts   : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
});

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    _author : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  , title    : String
  , body     : String
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

.. then you can:

```
Post.find({title: /caffeine/i}).populate('_author', null, {name: user.name}).run(function (err, posts) {
 res.render('view', {local: posts})
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Going to try this out asap :)

Comment: keep getting this errer:
_schema hasn't been registered for model "undefined"._
And In my schema i've done like this: owner: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'users' }

Comment: Confirm if the refered collection is `user` or `users`. Also, double check the case in the ref string. Try capitalizing it (`User`).

Comment: got it to work. The problem was I that need to drop the selection and create it agian. I was early morning, so didn't think about that :P Thanks again! :)